# nginx try_files to rewrite .html into "clean" url

Tags: nginx

Here's the directory containing static html files

```
public
|-- index.html
|-- media
|   `-- blurred_image-8.jpg
|-- post
|   `-- 13considerations
|       `-- index.html
```

I am attempting to configure nginx to convert all the urls ending with `.html` to strip out the suffix.

Like this:-

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  mysite.com;

    location / {
        root   /var/www/mysite/public;
        try_files  $uri  $uri/ $uri/index.html;
    }

    location /media/ {
        alias /var/www/mysite/public/media/;
        error_page 404 = /404;
        expires 30d;
    }

    location /static/ {
        alias /var/www/mysite/public/static/;
        error_page 404 = /404;
        expires 30d;
    }
}
```

This works properly for the homepage "http://mysite.com/" but if I attempt to access "http://mysite.com/post/13considerations/", I get a 500 internal server error.

What gives?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The example you're using works for returning the contents of a directory's `index.html` file, but will not work for files (e.g., `http://server/somedir/file` will not return the contents of `/somedir/file.html`).

A simplified configuration, which will return any HTML file without its extension *and* will use `index.html` for directories is as follows:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  mysite.com;

    index index.html;
    root /var/www/mysite/public;

    location / { 
        try_files $uri $uri/ @htmlext;
    }   

    location ~ \.html$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
    }   

    location @htmlext {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ $1.html last;
    }   
}
```

How it works:

- Specifying `index index.html` will default to using this file when directory URIs are accessed.
- Putting `root` outside the `location` block will apply server-wide.
- `try_files $uri $uri/ @htmlext` will look for an exact match for a file or directory first before finally trying to append `.html`.
- `try_files $uri =404` is to prevent Nginx getting stuck in a rewrite loop if a file can't be found.
- `rewrite ^(.*)$ $1.html last` appends `.html` and restarts the URI matching process.

Comment: This works very well except for one tiny flaw.  If I go to "mysite.com/index.html", it does not redirect to "mysite.com". And only for this particular `index.html`; for every other url, for example using my original question above, if I visit "mysite.com/post/13considerations/index.html", I do get redirected correctly to "mysite.com/post/13considerations/".

Comment: is this solution SEO friendly ? Just like the OP I also would like to know how to redirect the root path `/index.html` file to `/`

Comment: @xperator it's been a while since I wrote the configuration above, but it should serve the contents of `/index.html` for `/` on the all directories including the root (e.g., `http://example.com/`) because of the `index index.html` statement. Regarding SEO, the above takes the content of the file instead of redirecting, so you could try replacing `rewrite ^(.*)$ $1.html last;` with `rewrite ^(.*)$ $1.html redirect;` or `rewrite ^(.*)$ $1.html permanent;`

Comment: On routes which do not have a matching html file, there is a fatal error in Nginx: `rewrite or internal redirection cycle while redirect to named location "@htmlext"`. Is there any way to return a 404 instead?

Comment: It seems that using `break` instead of `last` in the `rewrite` directive will result in returning a 404 instead of a server error.