# Stripping index.html and .html from URLs with nginx

Tags: nginx

My basic goal is to serve the following clean URLs with nginx:

- `/` serves `/index.html`
- `/abc/` serves `/abc/index.html`
- `/abc/def` serves `/abc/def.html`
- `/abc` redirects to `/abc/`

In order to have canonical names for each resource, I also want to normalize any URL with superfluous file names or extensions:

- `/index.html` redirects to `/`
- `/abc/index.html` redirects to `/abc/`
- `/abc/def.html` redirects to `/abc/def`

The directives I thought would accomplish this:

```
index index.html;
try_files $uri.html $uri $uri/ =404;

# Redirect */index and */index.html to *.
rewrite ^(.*)/index(\.html)?$ $1 permanent;
# Redirect *.html to *.
rewrite ^(.+)\.html$          $1 permanent;
```

However, the result of this is different than I expected:

- `/`, `/index` and `/index.html` all redirect to `/` (loop).
- `/abc` and `/abc/` both redirect to `/abc/` (loop).

(It works as designed for `/abc/def.html` and `/abc/def`; only the directory URLs don't work.)

I'm not sure what is happening here; maybe I'm misunderstanding how the `rewrite` works?

(I already tried using location blocks instead, but this also results in loops as `try_files` performs an internal redirect to the location block that sends the HTTP 301.)

Edit: Fundamentally, I need something like a location block that only matches the original request URI, but is ignored for the purpose of internal redirects, so it doesn't create a loop in combination with the try_files directive.

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for a solution like [the one explained here](https://serverfault.com/questions/556207/nginx-try-files-to-rewrite-html-into-clean-url):

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  mysite.com;

    index index.html;
    root /var/www/mysite/public;

    location / { 
        try_files $uri $uri/ @htmlext;
    }   

    location ~ \.html$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
    }   

    location @htmlext {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ $1.html last;
    }   
}
```

Comment: Hm, that doesn't look quite correct - although the clean URLs are now served, the non-clean ones are also served rather than redirected. That behavior could have also been accomplished with only the `try_files $uri $uri.html $uri/ =404; index index.html;` directives. Did I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have found a solution, though I'm not experienced enough to tell if this could break in special cases or could be solved more easily in another way.

Basically, the problem is that a `location ~ ... {}` block does not only get matched on the original request URI, but also on the result of `try_files` and other rewrites. So if I have a location block to strip off the index.html or .html with a redirect, then it will not only run when a client requests `index.html` or `abc.html` directly, but also if the client requests `/` or `abc` and the server internally redirects these to `/index.html` and `abc.html` respectively, causing a redirect loop.

However, the redirect module provides an `if` directive which can check the `$request_uri` variable - this remains unchanged by internal redirects:

```
index index.html;
try_files $uri $uri.html $uri/ =404;

# like "location ~", but only for matching the original request. 
if ($request_uri ~ /index(.html)?$) {
  rewrite ^(.*/)index(.html)?$ $1 permanent;
}
if ($request_uri ~ \.html$) {
  rewrite ^(.*)\.html$ $1 permanent;
}
```

(Note that all of these directives now exist in the server context, without any location blocks.)

Comment: There's a problem with `$request_uri`: It's the raw URI part of the incoming request, meaning it will retain any query parameters if present.